# How to read a python binary string from Standard Input in Java

Tags: java, python, protocol-buffers, stdin

I have an python application using protocol buffers, and a Java application using protocol buffers too. What i want to do is just to be able to print the message (binary string after serializing) to the standard output. For this purpose i do the following in the Python app:

> def printMessage(self, protobuf_msg):
>
> > data = protobuf_msg.SerializeToString()
> >
> > sys.stdout.write(data)
> >
> > sys.stdout.flush()
>
> def main():
>
> > protobuf_msg = create_message()
> >
> > controller.printMessage(protobuf_msg)

And after that, i want to pipe this output (python pytonApp | java javaApp) and get this data with the javaApp and parse it. I've tried two options, doing this with the Protobuf API:

> protected ProtobufMsg receiveMsg() throws Exception{
>
> > ProtobufMsg message = null;
> >
> > message = protobuf_msg.parseFrom(System.in);
> >
> > return message;
> >
> > }

I have also try to do this with the BufferedInputStream in the following way:

> protected ProtobufMsg receiveMsg() throws Exception{
>
> > ProtobufMsg message = null;
> >
> > byte[] data = receiveFromStd();
> >
> > message = protobuf_msg.parseFrom(data);
> >
> > return message;
> >
> > }
>
> public byte[] receiveFromStd() throws Exception{
>
> > BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(System.in);
> >
> > byte[] out = new byte[1024];
> >
> > ```
> > int i=0;
> >
> > System.out.println("Entering While");
> >
> > while((out[i] = (byte)input.read())!= -1){
> >
> >     i++;
> > ```
> >
> > System.out.println("One byte readed");
> >
> > }
> >
> > ```
> > byte[] data_out = new byte[i];
> >
> > for(int l=0; l<data_out.length; l++){
> >
> >     data_out[l]=out[l];
> >
> > }
> >
> > return data_out;
> > ```
> >
> > }

So it's obvious i'm doing something wrong but i'm not able to realized what i'm doing wrong,
because it stays inside input.read()...

**EDIT:**
I have decided to change strategy and now i get first the size of packet, and afterwards the packet, as i'm using input.read(byte []) function...
The script i'm using is the following:

```
FIFO_FILE=/tmp/named_$$   # unique name ($$ is the PID of the bash process running this script)
mkfifo $FIFO_FILE   
export FIFO_FILE    # export the env variable
ant run &    # start a background process that reads the env variable and reads the fifo
cat > $FIFO_FILE #  reads the standard input and writes to the fifo 
rm $FIFO_FILE
```

And I call this as:  `python pythonApp.py | ./script` .

Comment: readLine() requires an end of line character to return or "unblock". so maybe you also need to also add `sys.stdout.write('\n')`

Comment: Hint: The `{}` button in the Stackoverflow editor turns the selected lines into properly indented, highlighted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `readLine()` since you have binary data.

1. Don't use the `Reader` API, you have binary data. Just use `BufferedInputStream`.
2. protobuf surely has an API to read directly from a stream. Use that. Don't forget to flush the output of the child or the data will sit forever in the 4K pipe buffer:

   ```
   sys.stdout.write(data)
   sys.stdout.flush()
   ```

Comment: The second one doesn't work because you only get an EOF when the child terminates. You really need to know in advance how many bytes to read. It was my impression that protobuf can do that, so the first call should work unless you forget to flush in the child.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried with the API of protobuf:  _protobufMsg.parseFrom(System.in)_;  and also, i tried with BufferedInputStream:  _BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(System.in);  while((out[i] = (byte)input.read())!= -1){ i++; }_. 
but in this case it stays at input.read() once and never reads any byte.
Thank you for your help @AaronDigulla.

Comment: I've flushed the output of python app, and i've tried with protobuf API and BufferedInputStream and still doesn't work... But i'm not sure if i'm using properly the BufferedInputStream...

Comment: Edit the question and show us both the Python code you use to send and the Java code you use to read.

Comment: Add `sys.stdout.flush()` after `sys.stdout.write(data)`

Comment: That is extremely odd. How do you create the pipe between the two processes?

Comment: I'm typing on terminal because my application is inside the contiki emulator Cooja:
 `python Controller | ant run`

Comment: Just for fun: Try to redirect the output of python to a file, wait for the message to arrive, stop Python. Then start `ant run < your-file` to the rest the message from there. Does that work? Maybe `ant` swallows the input. If that's the case, you will have to build the classpath manually and run `java -classpath ... com.pany.MainClass ...`

Comment: As You told me the problem is because ant swallows the input... instead of build the classpath manually i've decided to create an script that writes the output of my python app into a named pipe (fifo) and i read from this fifo in the java app with a BufferedInputStream. But at this moment i have one problem because it seems to read sometimes the same data twice, and i don't know why...

Comment: If you read the data twice, then Python is sending it twice. Add logging to both sides to see what happens.

Comment: It's ok to read from a named pipe using 
`File file = new File(fifo_file);
  FileInputStream input_file = new FileInputStream(file);
  BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(input_file);
                input.read(data);`
??

Comment: A named pipe works like any file except that you can't seek (hence you can't read any bit of data twice from it).

Comment: It was a problem of loosing data due to the fact that i was opening and closing the named pipe during my program. I've opened it in the constructor and now it works properly! Thank you very much for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment on Python side, but if it is a binary message you can do

```
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);

    message = Extension01.Message.parseFrom(in);
```

or if it is a delimited message:

```
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);

    message = Extension01.Message.parseDelimitedFrom(in);
```

There is no need to read it in as bytes